# How to draw watermark on Listbox using C#

Tags: c#, listbox, watermark

Is it possible to draw a **water mark** text or image on **ListBox**, in the following listbox, it contains several files which has the same file extension(file type, in this case it's .abc), so I want to draw the file extension as water mark,

[image]

any suggestions or guidance would be much appreciated & **Thanks** for your time..:)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "watermark"? Can you show us a mockup of what the design would look like? And what happens when you have a waveform with a *different* file extension? If you can guarantee that they'll all have the same extension, why not just hide the extension altogether?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, similar to ms word watermark, it may not sounds great but thought it would be nice especially for large file names, where they have to use scroll bar.                                     https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ms+word+watermark&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=EqLSUZX6Keen0AWxs4GgCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=799

Comment: So, something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1apzK.png)? You could just draw it yourself onto the ListBox. But I would recommend switching to a ListView control (which is more powerful than a ListBox anyway) and has built-in support for watermark images. However, this still doesn't answer the question of what happens when you have multiple different file extensions--there's no way to show multiple watermarks. So if your files always have the same extension, why not just omit the extension?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking to do, the list box will have same file extensions, so thought of doing it, and your suggestion sounds good too, I'll try that, thanks...

Comment: Ain't it easier just create label with text and set its position over your listbox?

Comment: @Tommi Not really, the label isn't transparent and you'll have problems with Z order.

Comment: Fair enough, transparency is really weak side of winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should do exactly what you are looking for:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // Example Item
  listBox1.Items.Add("c:\\Folder1\\example1.abc");
  listBox1.Items.Add("c:\\Folder1\\example2.abc");
  listBox1.Items.Add("c:\\Folder1\\example3.abc");
  listBox1.Items.Add("c:\\Folder1\\example4.abc");
  listBox1.Items.Add("c:\\Folder1\\example5.abc");
  listBox1.Items.Add("c:\\Folder1\\example6.abc");

  // Without this listBox1.DrawItem won't fire
  listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;

  // Subscribe event
  listBox1.DrawItem += listBox1_DrawItem;
}

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  // Make sure listbox contains items
  if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    return;

  // In this example ext will be ".abc"
  string ext = Path.GetExtension(listBox1.Items[0].ToString());

  // Draw items
  e.DrawBackground();
  e.DrawFocusRectangle();
  e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, SystemBrushes.WindowText, e.Bounds.Location);

  // Transparence
  // 255 = Full Visible
  //  0  = Invisible
  Color clr = Color.FromArgb(20, Color.Red);

  // Modify the position, font and Brush to your need
  e.Graphics.DrawString(ext, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, new SolidBrush(clr), new PointF(200F, 200F));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but doesn't seem to work, what happens is it'll draw string on top of list items, which results only the file extension    http://s16.postimg.org/t3eco4dg5/image.jpg

Comment: @San I thought this is exactly what you are looking for. Then I don't get your question.

Comment: I was expecting both the items, ie. list items and the file extension(.abc as watermark)  http://i.stack.imgur.com/1apzK.png